# Mocked method returns null when invocations are checked as well

Tags: spring, groovy, kotlin, spock

I'm not sure if I'm misusing interaction based testing or if I'm doing something conceptionally wrong. I'm working on a Spring Boot Application (Kotlin) and my tests are using Spock/Groovy.

I have a class under test which invokes another service to query information. The class under test is supposed to cache results. However, I'm not able to mock a method with a return value AND check the number of invocations, because the mocked method always returns null as soon as I add the check for invocation.

I created an isolated example, which demonstrates the issue.

This is the class under test:

```
@Service
class DemoService(private val downstreamService: DownstreamService) {
    fun demo(id: String): String {
        val something = downstreamService.something(id)
        return something
    }
}
```

which is using this service:

```
@Service
class DownstreamService {
    fun something(id: String): String {
        return id
    }
}
```

and this is how my tests look like:

```
class DemoServiceTest extends Specification {
    def downStream = Mock(DownstreamService)
    def demoService = new DemoService(downStream)

    def "value check"() {
        given:
        def test = "my test string"
        downStream.something(test) >> "xxx"

        when:
        def actual = demoService.demo(test)

        then:
        actual == "xxx" // works
    }   

    def "invocation check"() {
        given:
        def test = "my test string"
        downStream.something(test) >> "xxx"

        when:
        demoService.demo(test)

        then:
        1 * downStream.something(test) // works
    }

    def "combined check"() {
        given:
        def test = "my test string"
        downStream.something(test) >> "xxx"

        when:
        def demo = demoService.demo(test)

        then:
        1 * downStream.something(test)
        demo == "xxx" // fails because demo is null
    }

}
```

The first two tests are working as expected but the last one fails because the return value is always null when I add the check for the invocation.

Comment: See http://spockframework.org/spock/docs/1.3/all_in_one.html#_combining_mocking_and_stubbing

Comment: @LeonardBrünings It would help spot the information if there was a comment at the top of that example like `# This will not work`, the "not" in the sentence above is easy to miss... end of paragraph... visually hard to spot. Thank you.

Answer (score 8):

There is a problem in combining of mocking with invocation count checking, because mock is not called then.

You can rewrite your combined test in this way to have it working:

```
def "combined check"() {
    given:
    def test = 'my test string'

    when:
    def demo = demoService.demo(test)

    then:
    1 * downStream.something(test) >> 'xxx'
    demo == 'xxx'
}
```

Comment: This does not work well with Spring Webflux.  I can tell my mocked class to return a `Mono`, but it always returns `null`:  `1 * someService.getData(id) >> Mono.just(new Response())` will always return null if used in a `then` block.  Using Mockito seemed to work better :(

Answer (score 1):

Spock will interpret interactions based on * or >>, > operators.
And the interactions in then block will be having precedence over those in given or when: block.

Since the interaction in your then block doesn't specify a response, the default response will be null.

The interactions and stubbing should go together as mentioned in the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55918879/13163050)

You can refer to the documentation for a detailed explanation :)

1. [Where to declare interactions](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_where_to_declare_interactions)
2. [Combining Mocking and Stubbing](https://spockframework.org/spock/docs/2.0/all_in_one.html#_combining_mocking_and_stubbing)