# Mocking with Spock returns null for nested mocking and stubbing

Tags: java, unit-testing, groovy, mocking, spock

I am writing unit tests with Spock for a series of nested objects. The code I'm writing tests for is quite legacy and doesn't use dependency injection. However it is also quite mission-critical so I'd rather not touch it unless I really need to.

Here is the constructor of the class I'm trying to test:

```java
public SqlTable(Connection conn, String query) throws Exception {
    this.statement = conn.createStatement();
    this.resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

    meta = resultSet.getMetaData();
    int n = meta.getColumnCount();
    columns = new Column[n];

    for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
        columns[c] = new Column(meta.getColumnName(c+1));
        // ...
    }
}
```

In the tests I stub the nested mocks in a `.groovy` file, like this:

```scala
def "initialising a SQL table"() {
    given:
    def COL_NAME = "someColumnName"
    def mockResSetMeta = Mock(ResultSetMetaData) {
        getColumnCount() >> 1
        getColumnName(_ as int) >> COL_NAME
    }

    and:
    def mockResSet = Mock(ResultSet) {
        getMetaData() >> mockResSetMeta
    }

    and:
    def mockStatement = Mock(Statement) {
        executeQuery(_ as String) >> mockResSet
    }

    and:
    def mockConn = Mock(Connection) {
        createStatement() >> mockStatement
    }

    when: "SqlTable object"
    def table = new SqlTable(mockConn, "some query")

    then: "the table contains the categorical column"
    table.columns[0].getName() == COL_NAME
}
```

However the test fails. By debugging, I found that, in the `SqlTable` constructor, the mock for the `ResultSetMetaData` object, when `getColumnName()` is called, always returns `null`.

I did some digging, and it seems like this is due to how stubbing and mocking are handled together by Spock. I found two promising answers on SO:

- [Spock mock returns wrong value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41841668)
- [Mocked method returns null when invocations are checked as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55916321)

However for the life of me I wasn't able to modify the test in order to make it work.

Comment: It is kind of hard to reason about invisible code. There could be all kinds of reasons why this is not working. How about a minimal reproducer? Your Spock spec uses at least 5 classes I cannot see. I have no idea what they are doing. I also cannot magically know which kind of maybe popular library or API the classes originate from, because even your spec is incomplete (no import statements). Please enable others to reproduce your problem, that would be better than someone making educated guesses about why it might not work.

Comment: @kriegaex you're right, I added the code for the class constructor I'm trying to test. Please let me know if this is enough.

Comment: The actual code under test, despite still incomplete, indeed was key to answering the question more easily, because it makes the problem reproducible. Just parsing the test in my head was not that helpful, because the answer was quite subtle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Problem lies in this line `getColumnName(_ as int) >> COL_NAME`
it works when you change it to `getColumnName(_ as Integer) >> COL_NAME` or just `getColumnName(_) >> COL_NAME`.

My current assumptions as to why this is happening, is that the actual arguments in the mock are passed as an `Object[]` and that can't contain primitive types.

Here is a runnable reproducer

```
import spock.lang.*;
import java.sql.*;

class ASpec extends Specification {
    def "initialising a SQL table"() {
        given:
            def COL_NAME = "someColumnName"
            def mockResSetMeta = Mock(ResultSetMetaData) {
                getColumnCount() >> 1
                getColumnName(_ as Integer) >> COL_NAME
            }

        and:
            def mockResSet = Mock(ResultSet) {
                getMetaData() >> mockResSetMeta
            }

        and:
            def mockStatement = Mock(Statement) {
                executeQuery(_ as String) >> mockResSet
            }

        and:
            def mockConn = Mock(Connection) {
                createStatement() >> mockStatement
            }

        when: "SqlTable object"
        def table = new SqlTable(mockConn, "some query")

        then: "the table contains the categorical column"
        table.columns[0].getName() == COL_NAME
    }
}

@groovy.transform.Canonical
class Column {
    String name
}

class SqlTable {
    def columns
    public SqlTable(Connection conn, String query) throws Exception {
        def statement = conn.createStatement();
        def resultSet = statement.executeQuery(query);

        def meta = resultSet.getMetaData();
        int n = meta.getColumnCount();
        columns = new Column[n];

        for (int c = 0; c < n; c++) {
            columns[c] = new Column(meta.getColumnName(c+1));
            // ...
        }
    }
}
```

Try it in the [Groovy Web Console](https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_3_0&codez=eJyVU8Fu2zAMvfsrCJ-cZVDb67IUK7IeBjQdOu9WBIWiMJ46W0osOUkx5N9HWbZsJ82husiiH8lH8lEWG11aMBst_rKcq4x9mkTSG1_5jjOzzZ0pEjk3Bu7SDQrAg0W1MuAeci0Ft1Ir-BcBnRWuIZZKWslzaaTKgEP69ACWL3OMk1EDcyeTO1RfwrP1nv18eHm8m9_DFGKjC5zpvCrUIy8wPsMWRPsXmhTtHC0njzkZErJUuW2M37nl_awhO1ofeaYrZYnY7S3cXEa5_MkLcAM_lMUMy9qh5TrwO0bhydXqvMCO9BnhC0TbOjzLYdEfTp1abrFAFbIHw3vZ8YCisvhUYfnm609tSWM9YfJhFjOtVEvAfaNwInqPgSiR-AWSXQ-C6VLy_R_SF8TpNv_t1Ad6-UppOhU5LrUuiYjCPbTApCX42SsQtq76eNRFtj4yXU0AoZXlUhn3B2ghMNMlLUZOP5x6upw1nHmreb5eMBpvra0RTKdDPR0jquVbVmq9e2O25MqsdVmwGVdaudjNTnp9No3zwwFFEZ23R4QGdCvaEKjfm2qZS9FV343DlUVNaILWXRhRhaXeG7g_CNz0Fr-NbHrycu7sbH6TAb5stU_44MsGsvOJJ9HAr_ALH9zZYE-6HJKYOKU5PDtd-g7WNKRRggc9q0UvKTUfEhdNEOh6QtdXUHSNx6eqbacrFoNwyZBCPXUxvhn1WLhzdQWMsWA6Bi38B0einrk)

For future reference, I easily detect the issue by actually performing mocking and not just stubbing.

```
then:
1 * mockResSetMeta.getColumnName(_ as int) >> COL_NAME
```

will print

```
               1 * mockResSetMeta.getColumnName(_ as int) >> COL_NAME   (0 invocations)
            
               Unmatched invocations (ordered by similarity):
            
               1 * mockResSetMeta.getColumnName(1)
               One or more arguments(s) didn't match:
               0: argument instanceof int
                  |        |          |
                  |        false      int
                  1 (java.lang.Integer)
```

Comment: Again, you were faster than I. I was just about to post https://gwc-experiment.appspot.com/?g=groovy_2_5&gist=19677c37330c287794adeeb9132520ce during my tea break. 